# Calculating area of solar radiation using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, solar-radiation

How can I obtain area solar radiation using ArcGIS Desktop?

Answer (score 5):

I recommend a review of [An overview of the Solar Radiation tools](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000t4000000) from the ArcGIS Help 10.2, 10.2.1, and 10.2.2:

> The solar radiation analysis tools enable you to map and analyze the
>   effects of the sun over a geographic area for specific time periods.
>
> You can perform solar radiation analysis for a landscape or specific
>   location using two methods:
>
> - The Area Solar Radiation tool is used to calculate the insolation across an entire landscape. The calculations are repeated for each
>     location in the input topographic surface, producing insolation maps
>     for an entire geographic area.

That page has a link to [Area Solar Radiation (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Area_Solar_Radiation/009z000000t5000000/) which says that the tool:

> Derives incoming solar radiation from a raster surface